# How to format ndarrys in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two ndarrays. Each has three dimensions. They both contain multiple ndarrays and a float in the last dimension.

If I compare the types of each layer, everything seems fine. But if I want to access the shape the problem starts:

```
iterate = [x_train_orig2, x_train_orig]

for i in iterate:
    print(type(i))
    print(type(i[0]))
    print(type(i[0][0]))
    print(type(i[0][0][0]))
    print(i.shape)
```

-- Output

```
# My own aray: x_trainorig2
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float32'>
(1414,)

# Target array to match in shape: x_trainorig
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float32'>
(60000, 28, 28)
```

When I compare the first rows of both of the arrays I can see the difference, but I have no Idea how to even describe this problem and especially don't know how to solve it.

[image: Comparison of both of the arrays]

*The Goal* is to restructure x_train_orig2 so that there are still ndarrays inside ndarrays, but I can access, for example the shape.

I am pretty sure that this is a duplicate, I am already sorry. But I don't even know how to phrase my question correctly.

Comment: So what do you want to do ? Compare `x_train_orig2` with `x_train_orig` (e.g. compute the difference) ?

Comment: @gwido x_train_orig2 has ndarrys inside ndarrays, so that I can not access, for example the shape. I would like to have a 'plain' ndarray inside of ndarrays like in x_train_orig (see screenshot for the difference). And that is the problem. For my understanding they have the same structure, as shown with my experiment with 'type()', but my they screenshot shows, they aren't. And I don't know what it is.

Comment: Maybe the subarrays in `x_train_orig2` don't all have the same shape. Can you print the shapes ?

Comment: the shape of all below arrays is (12, 1369).

Comment: Does `np.shape(x_train_origin2)` help ? Do all the subarrays have the same type `dtype` ?
What are the differences in the way you construct / load the two arrays ?